# Stanford CoreNLP: StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 54686973

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

So I'm trying to write a very simple program with Stanford's CoreNLP, but I haven't gotten very far before getting a StreamCorruptedException. I am using Scala, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Here's the code:

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val str = "The dog went to the park."
    val props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, depparse");
    val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // more to be added
  }
}
```

When I try to run this code (sbt run), I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 54686973
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.readConfig(TaggerConfig.java:748)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:803)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:766)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:297)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:262)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:97)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:77)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(AnnotatorImplementations.java:57)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$4.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:276)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:289)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:126)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:122)
  at Hello$.main(Hello.scala:13)
  at Hello.main(Hello.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you don't have the models and CoreNLP can't load them. In order to run CoreNLP, you need to have both `stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar` and `stanford-corenlp-3.5.0-models.jar`. Both should be added to you build path.

Comment: Woops, I totally forgot to add the models to my build path!

Thank you very much!

Relavent lines in build.sbt: libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.0",
      "edu.stanford.nlp" % "stanford-corenlp" % "3.5.0" classifier "models"
    )

Comment: Hi Todd—if this resolves your question, please mark the answer as accepted (green check-mark button to the left). This gives Augustin some points :)